# Current user duration or current user page count in magento 2

Tags: magento2, session, customer-session, user

I have a custom module . In my observer i have to know the current user duration & current user ip in fronted . So i write the code for user ip . Now if a user visit my website i want to get is this is the first page he visited in my website.

For example i have home , about, contact page . So when customer first time visit home then i have to get count=1 , if customer visiting about after home page then count =2 , if customer visiting  contact after about then count=3 etc. Is there any method i can get this ?

Or visiting pages i want to know how much duration he is in the website . If the visitor closed window and take the website again the time should start from zero .

I have to solve this question in order to get answer for [getStoreCurrency VS getCurrentCurrency ( compare store currency & getCurrentCurrency)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/323119/getstorecurrency-vs-getcurrentcurrency-compare-store-currency-getcurrentcurr)

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use a session variable for this? Maybe add to it a cookie only valid for the current session. If that cookie doesn’t already exist: initialize counter with 1 and any other data you want to capture (landing page, referrer, etc); otherwise, increment the current value.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code:

> app/code/Shasha/CustomModule/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
  <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
      <observer name="browser_predispatch" instance="Shasha/CustomModule\Observer\BrowserPredispatch" shared="false" />
  </event>
</config>
```

> app/code/Shasha/CustomModule/Observer/BrowserPredispatch.php

```
<?php

namespace Shasha\CustomModule\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;


class BrowserPredispatch implements ObserverInterface {

    protected $_session;
    
    protected $request;
    
    
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $session,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,

    )
    {
        $this->_session     =    $session;
        $this->request      =    $request;
    }


    /*
     * Observer that works on every page load
     *
    */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $request        = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
        $controller     = $this->request->getControllerName();
        $module         = $this->request->getModuleName();
        if($module == 'cms'){
            // write here your counter logic to set in session or cookie
        }
                
        $visitor      = $this->_session->getVisitorData(); // visitor all details
        
                        
    }
    
}
```

**I hope it helps you**.